# MongoDB nested search query parameters

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Is there a chance I can query the MongoDB record using `findOneAndUpdate`, or `findByIdAndUpdate` by triggering the record by the `"ID"` **and** `"lang"` fields? Here is the database object sample:

```json
{
        "id": "61842e6fb19afbc0922f5505",
        "locales": [
          {
            "lang": "ru",
            "title": "Тестовый десерт",
            "description": "тестовый"
          },
          {
            "lang": "lv",
            "title": "Testu deserts",
            "description": "Testu descriptions"
          },
          {
            "lang": "en",
            "title": "Test dessert",
            "description": "Test description"
          }
        ]
}
```

And this is how I attempt to trigger, and it doesn't work:

```js
const filter = {
  _id: id,
  locales: {
    lang: lang
  }
}

const product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(filter, {
  lang: {
    title,
    description,
    price
  }
}, { new: true });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$set` operator like that:

```
const product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: "61842e6fb19afbc0922f5505",
  "locales.lang": "ru"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "locales.$": {
      lang: "ru",
      title: "title",
      description: "desription",
      price: 23
    }
  }
})
```

Working playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oBNS6wtK50g

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked